# WAMP WORDPRESS connects to MySQL but will not connect to MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mariadb, database-connection

Wordpress cannot establish a connection to `MariaDB` only connects to `MySQL`
Keep getting: `Can’t select database`
How to set Wordpress to connect to `MariaDB`?

[image]

Disabling or Enabling MySQL doesn't help either

[image]

This too does NOT work

[image]

Here is the PhpMyAdmin database view
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Got it working. 
I had to set up the sample Config file to look like below and save it as `wp_config.php`

```
 // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
    /** The name of the database for WordPress */
    define( 'DB_NAME', 'wp_db' );

    /** MySQL database username */
    define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

    /** MySQL database password */
    define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );


#Here is the MOST IMPORTANT of all
    /** MySQL hostname */
    define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:3307' );#IMPORTAT: Notice the :3307 that is the PORT for MariaDB


    /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
    define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

    /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
    define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

And Voila!
Somehow I spent days and hours of Googling and banging my head everywhere, but the solution was as simple as that.

Comment: Yes, I had it the other way (WAMP WORDPRESS connects to MariaDB but will not connect to MySQL). Found the port for MySQL in left-click WAMP menu, Mysql, blue line "port used by MySQL" - it was 3308. Had to set `localhost:3308`